# socket chat room python - crashes right after a file transfer from client to server

Tags: python, while-loop, python-sockets

I've created a chat room in python using socket (a server, any number of clients)
the thing is that everything works flawlessly until a client sends a file, even the file transfer is completed on both the ends but the server side just freezes, i confirmed it by using print statement after the file transfer loop the client side seems to print it whereas on the server side i get no output. I am attaching those file transfer parts alone from both server and client side....

CLIENT SIDE:

```
def sendfile(self):
    while True:
        SEPARATOR='<SEPARATOR>'
        abc='file'
        filename=askopenfile(mode='rb')
        filename=os.path.abspath(filename.name)
        filesize=os.path.getsize(filename)
        client.send(f"{abc}{SEPARATOR}{filename}{SEPARATOR}{filesize}".encode())
        with open(filename,'rb')as f:
            while True:
                bytes_read=f.read(20480)
                if not bytes_read:
                    break
                client.sendall(bytes_read)
                progress.update(len(bytes_read))
        print('uploading completed')
        break
```

SERVER SIDE:

```
def handle(client):
    def filereceive(ms):
        while True:
            waste,filename,filesize=ms.split(SEPARATOR)
            filename=os.path.basename(filename)
            filename=filename[:-4]+'COOPY'+filename[-4:]
            filesize=int(filesize)
            with open(filename,'wb')as f:
                while True:
                    bytes_read=client.recv(20480)
                    if not bytes_read:
                        break
                    f.write(bytes_read)
            print('completed')
            handle(client)
            break
```

In short in the Server side it never prints completed which signifies its stuck there, eventhough the file transfer is completed. Kindly help me with this.........

Comment: I even tried using  this in server side.....       
`with open(filename,'wb')as f:
                while True:
                    print('hello world')
                    bytes_read=client.recv(20480)
                    while bytes_read:
                        f.write(bytes_read)
                        bytes_read=client.recv(20480)
                  
                print('completed')
                handle(client)`